# Custom buttons for php poll

Tags: php, html

I'm making a site for my friend and I. The main feature is a poll, asking who is better. I have the input type set as radio. I want to know if I could make the poll use my custom images as buttons instead of just a circle I click on. One button has my name, the other has my friend's.

Here's the code currently:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <meta name="author" content="My Name">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" rev="stylesheet" href="divs.css"
            type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" rev="stylesheet" href="styles.css"
            type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />

        <script>
            function getVote(int) {
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                            }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById("poll").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
                                }
                    xmlhttp.open("GET","poll_vote.php?vote="+int,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
                }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="all"> <!-- Start All Div -->

            <div id="header"> <!-- Start Header Div -->

                <embed width="800" height="100px" src="../Media/Banner/banner.swf">
                <embed width="800" height="50px" src="../Media/DD Menu/ddmenu3.swf">

            </div> <!-- End Header Div -->

            <div id="main"> <!-- Start Main Div -->

                <div id="poll">
                    <h3>Me or Friend?</h3>
                    <form>
                    Me:
                    <input type="radio" name="vote" value="0" onclick="getVote(this.value)">
                    <br>
                    Friend:
                    <input type="radio" name="vote" value="1" onclick="getVote(this.value)">
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div> <!-- End Main Div -->

            <div id="footer"> <!-- Start Footer Div -->

                <p class="footer">&copy; Copyright,
                    2014 - <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                                        var today = new Date()
                                        var year = today.getFullYear()
                                        document.write(year)
                                    </script></p> 

            </div> <!-- End Footer Div -->

        </div> <!-- End All Div -->

    </body>
</html>


<?php
$vote = $_REQUEST['vote'];

//get content of textfile
$filename = "poll_result.txt";
$content = file($filename);

//put content in array
$array = explode("||", $content[0]);
$yes = $array[0];
$no = $array[1];

if ($vote == 0) {
  $yes = $yes + 1;
}
if ($vote == 1) {
  $no = $no + 1;
}

//insert votes to txt file
$insertvote = $yes."||".$no;
$fp = fopen($filename,"w");
fputs($fp,$insertvote);
fclose($fp);
?>

<h2>Result:</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Yes:</td>
<td>
<img src="poll.gif"
width='<?php echo(100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2)); ?>'
height='20'>
<?php echo(100*round($yes/($no+$yes),2)); ?>%
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>No:</td>
<td>
<img src="poll.gif"
width='<?php echo(100*round($no/($no+$yes),2)); ?>'
height='20'>
<?php echo(100*round($no/($no+$yes),2)); ?>%
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Look into the `:before` pseudo element. You might be able to place something over the normal circles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely, but it will be with javascript. Here's an example using Jquery. Notice that the input radio is positioned off screen so it can be set without being seen by the user.

HTML

```
<p>Choice 1</p>
<img id="choice-1" class="button" src="path/to/img.png"/>
<input id="choice-1-input" type="radio" name="vote" value="0" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px" onclick="getVote(this.value)">
```

JavaScript with Jquery. Included the context as requested.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#choice-1').click(function()
  {
    radiobtn = document.getElementById("#choice-1-input");
    radiobtn.checked = true;
  });

}
```

Comment: Made an edit to the html and javascript. Didn't use a selector for the radio button. It should work now.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am a bit noobish, so where do I insert the js?

Comment: Anywhere inside the document ready function. Like this. $(document).ready(function() { *HERE* }. I'll make an edit to clarify.

Comment: Did it work? If not, please give me more information. If it is working, please mark my answer as correct.